# Links in comments are broken on the new "about" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown-rendering, tour

It looks like the `[text](url)` link markup is not parsed (correctly) in comments shown on [the fancy new "about" page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/).  As pictures speak more than a thousand words, here's a screenshot from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/about:

[image: Screenshot]

(Also, [here's a link to the comment shown in the screenshot](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/269), to confirm that the breakage does not occur when it's viewed normally.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This next build will fix this.